# How to connect to git code spaces via ssh from another machine?

Tags: git, github, github-codespaces

I have git code space

I want to use my other machine MacBook Pro to connect to that specific git code space via ssh

How do I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try first to install and use the [GitHub CLI `gh`](https://cli.github.com/manual/) (see [installation](https://github.com/cli/cli#installation))

From there, following [SSH into a codespace](https://docs.github.com/en/codespaces/developing-in-codespaces/using-github-codespaces-with-github-cli#ssh-into-a-codespace)

```
gh codespace ssh -c CODESPACE-NAME
```

---

> Note: The codespace you connect to must be running an SSH server.
>
> The default container image includes an SSH server, which is started automatically.
>
> If your codespaces are not created from the default image, you can install and start an SSH server by adding the following to the features object in your `devcontainer.json` file.
>
> ```yaml
> "features": {
>    ...
>    "ghcr.io/devcontainers/features/sshd:1": {
>        "version": "latest"
>    },
>    ...
> }
> ```